# Amazon_Core schema: current version - 2.1.3, required version - 2.2.14

Tags: magento2

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your
>   database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root
>   directory. The following modules are outdated: Amazon_Core schema:
>   current version - 2.1.3, required version - 2.2.14 Amazon_Core data:
>   current version - 2.1.3, required version - 2.2.14 Amazon_Login
>   schema: current version - 2.1.3, required version - 2.2.14
>   Amazon_Login data: current version - 2.1.3, required version - 2.2.14
>   Amazon_Payment schema: current version - 2.1.3, required version -
>   2.2.14 Amazon_Payment data: current version - 2.1.3, required version - 2.2.14 Magento_CatalogWidget schema: current version - 2.0.0, required version - 2.0.1 Magento_CatalogWidget data: current version -
>   2.0.0, required version - 2.0.1 Dotdigitalgroup_Email schema: current version - 2.7.1, required version - 2.7.2 Dotdigitalgroup_Email data:
>   current version - 2.7.1, required version - 2.7.2

Comment: if you want help, help us to understand what you did, and what you want

Comment: please help me this message coming up

Comment: What did you do to get this message ?

Comment: this is my site www.yoursaw.co.uk

Comment: Try to execute this : `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` in CLI

Comment: but i dont know how to execute the comment.can you help me out

Comment: You need to know the minimum magento knowledge to be able to do this

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you have updated the Amazon module, please run this :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove Amazon_Core module entry from the setup_resource table of the database and run below command in the command line.
Open cmd and go to the Magento project folder like
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento and run below command.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Still, you are facing the issue please let me know.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but this could be a module version error.

I have recently encountered this when my data_version was altered accidentally while creating a new module.

I had to update/reset the module version within these areas on the Database:

`update setup_module set schema_version = "1.0.x" where module = "Your_Module";`
`update eav_attribute set data_version = "1.0.x" where module = "Your_Module";`

However, I agree with @PЯINCƏ that a setup:upgrade is required.